# Date command - adjusting the date works on my mac but NOT the server's shell

Tags: command-line, date

On my mac I can ask for the date in threes days time:

```
Josephs-MacBook-Pro-3$date -v 3d 
Fri  3 Oct 2014 08:54:26 BST
Josephs-MacBook-Pro-3$
```

but when I try that on my dreamhost server:

```
joereddington@blout:~/Jurgen/nextActions/commands$ date -v 3d
date: invalid option -- 'v'
Try `date --help' for more information.
joereddington@blout:~/Jurgen/nextActions/commands$ date --version
date (GNU coreutils) 8.13
Copyright (C) 2011 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>.
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Written by David MacKenzie.
joereddington@blout:~/Jurgen/nextActions/commands$
```

Is there a different switch I should be using? Or is the feature simply unavailable?

Comment: See [Date calculation using GNU date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5655026/date-calculation-using-gnu-date)

Comment: three days ago would be `date -v -3d`.

Answer (score 1):

dreamhost servers run `debian` linux which uses the GNU version of date. GNU date does not support the -v option.

On OSX the `date` command is the BSD variant - which has more extensive options than GNU date - and includes the -v option to adjust the date.